# Trying to load json from assets in android studio

Tags: java, android, json

Here is my code:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("index.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
```

I get an error underlining the last row:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
```

saying:

> Unhandled Exception org.json.JSONException

Comment: So there was a problem in converting your string to json.  I'd check to make sure your file is legal json, and to make sure your file is being read in properly and returning the correct string in loadJsonFromAsset.

Comment: I tried several json and still got that error, even tried http://jsonlint.com/ to validate my json. It says it is valid.

Comment: That doesn't mean you're parsing it right. It's the top level an object or array? Is the server sending garbage? Or are you throwing an io exception and passing it null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped all your `InputStream` operations in a `try` block catching `IOException`.  What the error is telling you is that you need to wrap that last line in a `try` block that catches `JSONException`.

You can use a different `try` block, but better design is to use the same `try` block, put that statement inside the block and catch `JSONException` as well as `IOException` in that block.  Then have your method return a `JSONObject` rather than a `String`.

Comment: ok got it. Now the error is gone. But how to test if the JSONAttey was loaded correctly?

Comment: That's what the JSONException is for; if you don't catch a JSONException, then you know your object loaded correctly.

Comment: ok,I see in the first step the json file was found and the String was loaded correctly, so i end up with a string containing the json. However it can not be converted into a JSONArray or JSONobject. Already tried another json file aswell.Following Function is always returning null. Here is my code: `public JSONArray GetArrey() {
        JSONArray object = null;
        try {
            object = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset());
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return object;
    }`

Comment: Okay, so after you create your String, put System.out.println(json); after it and see if your string is what you're expecting.  You may have an encoding mismatch too, if you are decoding your bytes as UTF-8 and your original file is in some other encoding.  You may have to step through with a debugger or use some other methods to find the problem.  It's easy to write code; when things aren't working is when the real work of programming begins.  :)  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for ur help, but yeah code printIn is as expected. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Fantastic!  Please accept my answer as correct.  My co-worker has a 90K reputation and I'm trying to catch up.  :)